# Texmaker can't find the image

Tags: graphics, paths

I'm writing my master thesis using texmaker as editor... I have a multi-file project with a main-file as master document and another file used as input.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \input{body/part1}
\end{document}
```

in the part1.tex file I used include graphics to get a PDF image:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{../images/RAM.pdf}
\caption{Availability diagram}
\end{figure}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File '../images/RAM.pdf' not found.
```

So, what I have to do to sole it?

Comment: it seems a relative-path issue. Since `\input` does nothing else than expanding code in your subfile, the relative path of your graphic (`\includegraphics[<options>]{<path>}`) should be indicated relatively to your `<master-file>.tex`

Comment: BTW: this has nothing to do with texmaker (common confusion among new users), texmaker just calls latex

Comment: @ebo i will try that and come back to you

Comment: @daleif oh yes i'm a new user :)

Comment: May be a dumb question, but does your file "RAM.pdf" is actually named like that? What I mean is that in LINUX you can avoid having the extension of the file (e.g. .pdf, .png, etc.) and that cause problems while compiling in LaTeX. I recommend you to make sure of that and try to recompile it. Another problem may be is that your relative path is incorrect and that's the reason LaTeX doesn't find it. Hope this may help you.

Comment: @AnoirNechi So be [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I've edited your question in order to create a real [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Check out more about it following the link, and update your MWE according to your case.

Comment: @ebo : Sorry i was a little busy  ... anyway the problem was with compilation options I've changed to include DVI and now it can see the images. Thank you so much ebo